# Is there a preprocessor directive known as micro?

Tags: c, macros

In class we were going over processor directives, and I have in my notes some functions labeled `macro` and some labeled `micro`. I'm not sure if `micro` is it's own entity or if I just misunderstood the professor that day.

I've web-searched it, but I wanted to double check.

Is there really such an item as a `micro` (that you would learn in an Intro to C class), and if so how is it different than a `macro`?

Edit:

My notes look like this:

Macro

```
#define CIRCLE(radius) 3.1415 *radius*radius
#define MAX(a,b) (a>b)?a:b
```

Micro

```
#define PRINT_ARRAY(A,N){\
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)\
    printf("%d\n",A[i]);\
    }
```

But I suspect that what I labelled as `Micro` is also a `Macro`.

Comment: I doubt it. Can you give us some context, e.g. something from your class with the word 'micro' in it?

Comment: Probably not. Macros would refer to preprocessor definitions using `#define`. I've been using C/C++ for almost 20 years and I don't know what a "micro" would refer to.

Comment: There are only macros, no "micros".

Comment: Sounds like a mistake in your notes...

Comment: what year was this?  might have been a computer type ("micro-computer")  People called PCs this back in the day.

Comment: Could you provide an example paragraph? It's hard to be certain without context.

Comment: There is the term microPROCESSOR...

Comment: I did a CTRL+F in the C standard. There are only three instances of micro and in all three instances they refer to microprocessors.

Comment: micro optimisation is something you shouldn't do. microwave ovens usually make me food while I program. uber-micro is what you need for a zerg rush. I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: [Etymology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/macro?s=t): "_macro_, n. (5) Also called macroinstruction. Computers. an instruction that represents a sequence of instructions in abbreviated form." So the two words really _are_ related. In terms of words you might have heard in a CS class, there's also [microcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode), but that's something else entirely.

Comment: trolling or at least sort of ...

Comment: @alk Not really. I've web searched it, like I mentioned, but I turned up nothing, and to double check, I came here, because someone may have the same question in the future. My teacher has a thick accent and can be hard to understand sometimes. Clearly, the consensus is that I misunderstood, which I brought up in the question. I wanted to double check though.

Comment: Sorry if this is a worthless question. I wanted to be sure before I went into my final.

Comment: @Hogan I think it was a case of me misunderstanding. This was last week, we were talking about preprocessor directives.

Comment: Now that you have the example that is def. a micro @jfa

Comment: This is a conceptual question; this question does not have to do with code written. Therefore, the rule that "Questions **concerning problems with code you've written** must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself" does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a 2011 draft of the standard.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) You will see that there is no such thing. There are only macros, and most probably the professor made a typo or was referring to something else.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is anything called MICRO in C. The best I can search on Google is [Grantronics: Micro/C Compilers](http://www.grantronics.com.au/micro-c.html) or [MicroC/OS-II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroC/OS-II) which is basically an acronym for **Micro-Controller Operating Systems Version 2**.

However in C you have MACRO

**EDIT:-**

Your edit confirms that you have made a typo as that is clearly a **MACRO in C**. The below code which you have written is a MACRO.

```
#define PRINT_ARRAY(A,N){\
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)\
    printf("%d\n",A[i]);\
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No. In C, a macro is a preprocessor directive. Basically, it is a name given to a piece of code. In the first stage of compilation, the preprocessor replaces all occurences of that name with the code. Here is more information: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

The language does not define micros, but they may be something user-defined, like a data dype for example.

Answer (score 1):

In light of your edit you likely just made a mistake in your notes. What you have under "micro" is in fact a C macro.